# Seeking explanation of the hg38 files downloaded from bowtie 2 website

Tags: sequence-alignment, genome, human, bowtie2

I downloaded the H. sapiens, NCBI GRCh38 files from Bowtie's website. After unzipping, there are 6 files, 4 that end in set 1.ebwt, set2.ebwt, set3.ebwt, and set4.ebwt and two that end in set.rev.1.ebwt and set.rev.2.ebwt.

I am unable to find any explanation for what these files are either online.

which one do I use for bowtie2 mapping?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Bowtie is providing you with the index files for hg38.  This are the result of the [bowtie2-build indexer](http://bowtie-bio.sourceforge.net/bowtie2/manual.shtml#the-bowtie2-build-indexer).  However you have downloaded the indexes for Bowtie1 not bowtie2

> Bowtie 2’s .bt2 index format is different from Bowtie 1’s .ebwt
>   format, and they are not compatible with each other.

Then according to the [manual](http://bowtie-bio.sourceforge.net/bowtie2/manual.shtml#command-line) you pass the basename of the index for the reference genome. So this should be the name prior to the extension, .1.bt2 for Bowtie2.

```
bowtie2 [options]* -x <bt2-idx> {-1 <m1> -2 <m2> | -U <r> | --interleaved <i>} -S [<sam>]
Main arguments
-x <bt2-idx>
The basename of the index for the reference genome. The basename is the name of any of the index files up to but not including the final .1.bt2 / .rev.1.bt2 / etc. bowtie2 looks for the specified index first in the current directory, then in the directory specified in the BOWTIE2_INDEXES environment variable.
```